# questionaire time spend mysql

Tags: sql, database-normalization

Say I have a table where I would store questions.
Now I would like to track how much time people on average spend per question and how many came up with the right solution.

1. Would I store the time spend per question in the table_questions itself or in a different one.
2. Would I store the answered right in the table_questions or in a seperate one, maybe even with time spend.

The reason why I am hesitating is two fold. First off I rather not want the user to be able to perform update queries on my questions. But seperating the time spend and "answered good" in a different table seems weird to me because they are inherent to the question?

Does anyone with normalization talent (unlike me) know what would be a good approach?

Comment: The answer to both questions is probably a different one.  If your table_questions table has any user information it's name is misleading.

Comment: Sorry I should have explain it better. I am not storing "specific" users. I just wanna track users "in general"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

Don't name tables TABLE_QUESTIONS or TABLE_USERS or anything similar, unless you have a good reason, and I cannot think of one at the moment. Just call them QUESTIONS and USERS.

If you actually have a USERS table, and you care who answers correctly (I cannot tell based on the wording of the question), then I think you should also have a USER_QUESTIONS table. The tables might look like this:

```
QUESTIONS
---------
Question_Id    
Question_Descr

USERS
-----
User_Id        
User_Name

USER_QUESTIONS
--------------
Question_Id
User_Id
Answer
Grade
StartTime
EndTime
```

Then questions (and only questions) go in their own table, and users (and only users) go in their own table. But when a user answers a question, it goes in the mixed table.

You have a many-to-many relationship between users and questions, and creating an intermediate table like this is the normal way of resolving that.

Comment: Would you use the same approach if you wanna track per question the time spend so not user specific time but on the question itself in general?

Comment: @ObiWanKenobi -- I would. Otherwise, it's hard to calculate the proper average. If the average is 3.1 minutes say, and someone takes 10 minutes, how does that affect the average? In order to know, you would have to store more than the one number -- at least the count of people. But 10 could be a misleading outlier, and so even with the count you get hard to interpret results. So yes, I would save them separately. But I am sure others would have different ideas.

Comment: Thx MJB for your reply! I really appreciate it.I'll probably will do as you propose. I first wanted to calculate - with php - the average time based on the count(question is done x times) and than use that as a divider. So say average is 1 min with the question answered 9 times and the current person takes 10 min. the average is than  (9*1 min + 1*10 min) /10.  I am/was sort of afraid that over time the table storing all this will get larger than useable?  Anyone else wanna shed his wisdom on this matter?